# livedata notifies new observer

Tags: android, android-livedata

in livedata's observe method there is a comment like

> Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of the given owner. The events are dispatched on the main thread. If LiveData already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer.

When i try to add a new observer to an existing livedata instance and if livedata has a data set, new observer's onChanged method calls.

Is there a way that may avoid this behaviour? I just don't want to be notified for new observers

SingleLiveEvent is not covering my case exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of LiveData starts observers version from its default version which is -1, new observers get notify from previous livedata value change. Here is livedata's ObserverWrapperClass

```
private abstract class ObserverWrapper {
    final Observer<T> mObserver;
    boolean mActive;
    int mLastVersion = START_VERSION;

    ObserverWrapper(Observer<T> observer) {
        mObserver = observer;
    }

    abstract boolean shouldBeActive();

    ...rest of class ...
    }
```

Instead i created custom ObserverWrapper and started new observers from livedata's last version.

```
public class MyObserverWrapper<T> {
final Observer<T> observer;
int lastVersion;

public MyObserverWrapper(Observer<T> observer, int version) {
    this.observer = observer;
    lastVersion = version;
}
}
```

And in my custom livedata class i checked observer's version if it is smaller than livedata's version. If so,i notified observer.

```
public class SingleLiveEvent<T> extends MutableLiveData<T> {

public int version;
private MyObserverWrapper observerWrapper;
private Map<String, MyObserverWrapper> observerWrapperMap = new HashMap<>();

public void observe(LifecycleOwner owner, MyObserverWrapper observerWrapper) {
    observerWrapperMap.put(owner.getClass().getName(), observerWrapper);
    observe(owner, observerWrapper.observer);
}

@MainThread
public void observe(final LifecycleOwner owner, final Observer<T> observer) {

    // Observe the internal MutableLiveData
    super.observe(owner, new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable T t) {
            for (String lifecycleOwnerName : observerWrapperMap.keySet()) {
                if (lifecycleOwnerName.equals(owner.getClass().getName())) {
                    observerWrapper = observerWrapperMap.get(lifecycleOwnerName);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (observerWrapper.lastVersion < version) {
                observer.onChanged(t);
            }
        }
    });
}

@MainThread
public void setValue(@Nullable T t) {
    version++;
    super.setValue(t);
}
}
```